# На телефоне Xiaomi не меняются иконки уведомлений

Tags: android, icon

Меняю стандартные иконки методами setLargeIcon и setSmallIcon, на  samsung и htc все работает, на Xiaomi нет, показывает стандартных роботов в панели уведомлений и шторке. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146059/java-android-redmi-3-miui-notification-icons-cannot-be-changed

Comment: то что надо, спасибо